# Resolve Arbitrary Hostname/IP Address in C#

Tags: c#, .net, debugging

I'm writing behavior tests in C#, using Selenium and the Chrome web driver.  In addition to local debugging, I also want to test changes in a staging context, by forcing C# to resolve our site's hostname to a staging IP address.

Is there a way to set an arbitrary IP address for a given hostname, without editing C:\windows\system32\drivers\etc\hosts, and without setting actual DNS records?

For example, when I make the following call, I want Selenium to go to an IP address that I can manually set within the context of my debugging application:

```
using(var driver = new ChromeDriver())
{
    driver.Navigate().GoToUrl(url);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your behavior tests should take/read some configuration source (custom config file, environment variables, etc) during setup step and takes the site address from that source. So instead of changing hosts file or code in your tests, you just change configuration settings.

Also, in the ideal world, you should have different hostnames for staging and prod environment... And in your case, you can use IP address in your tests directly, instead of hostname.

Comment: Your answer has nothing to do with the question I asked.  Thanks for the advice, but no thanks.

Comment: @v623 my point is that you should think in the other direction, not about workaround with the hostname resolving, as this is more like a dirty hack

Answer (score 0):

You could just add the value to your app.config and change the url based on the environment you want to use.

```
    //app.config file
    <add key="URL" value="http://123.45.67.89/" />


   using System.Configuration;

   using(var driver = new ChromeDriver())
   {

   driver.Navigate().GoToUrl(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["URL"]);
   }
```